# IntelliJ Idea error "Module 'api' production: java.lang.AbstractMethodError"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-plugin

For some reason I get this error when I am trying to build an SBT project.

- IntelliJ version: 13.1.5 (just updated)
- Scala plugin version: 0.41.2
- SBT plugin: 1.6.1

  ```
  Error:Module 'api' production: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
  org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ChunkExclusionService.isExcluded(Lorg/jetbrains/jps/ModuleChunk;Lorg/jetbrains/jps/model/JpsGlobal;)Z
  ```

Action: Build/Rebuild and then very shortly it stops.

Can someone please help me?